# How to init parameters to post when using active_model_serializers with Rails 5 API and RSpec

Tags: rspec-rails, active-model-serializers

I followed the AMS [guide](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/integrations/ember-and-json-api.md) to set up a Rails API app to use with Ember.
The problem I have is how to create a params to pass in to the controller action ?
I used the following in a RSpec request spec to init valid params to pass in to the post action:

```
context 'when shop does not have yet the selected language' do
      let(:new_language) { create(:language, tag: 'nl-BE') }
      let(:valid_params) { { language_id: new_language.id } }

      before { post "/shops/#{shop_id}/languages", params: valid_params.to_json, headers: headers }

      it 'returns status code 201' do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(201)
      end

      it 'has a new language added' do
        expect(json['data'].size).to eq(2)
      end
    end
```

It worked before the changes I made in the `ShopLanguagesController` strong parameters method:

**Before**

```
def shop_language_params
  params.require(:shop_language).permit(:shop_id, :language_id, :modified_by)
end
```

**After**

```
def shop_language_params
  ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!(params, only: [:shop, :language, :modified_by] )
end
```

It seems like ActiveModelSerializers is expecting a different params structure containing `data` key:

```
ActiveModelSerializers::Adapter::JsonApi::Deserialization::InvalidDocument:
       Invalid payload ({:data=>"Expected hash"}): {"language_id"=>2, "controller"=>"shop_languages", "action"=>"create", "shop_id"=>"1", "shop_language"=>{"language_id"=>2}}
```

I tried to modify `valid_params` by adding `data` key as follows:

```
let(:valid_params) { { data: { language: new_language, shop: user.shop } } }
```

Now the params I pass in to the controller look like that:

```
params: {"data":{"language":{"id":2,"tag":"nl-BE","created_at":"2018-04-11T08:29:46.299Z","updated_at":"2018-04-11T08:29:46.299Z"},"shop":{"id":1,"category":"Qui","fax":"(650) 065-5773","identifier":26168,"leader":"KELLEY LEHNER","modified_by":"Ms. Nelle Kuhlman","name":"CASSIN-WILL","opening_date":"2018-03-29","phone":"928.823.7550 x225","status":"tmp_closed","created_at":"2018-04-11T08:29:46.231Z","updated_at":"2018-04-11T08:29:46.231Z"}}}
```

But it does not either.

Here are the params coming to the controller from Ember:

*Before* being parsed by `ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!`:

```
controller params: <ActionController::Parameters {"data"=>{"attributes"=>{"modified-by"=>"Z28SCAMB"}, "relationships"=>{"shop"=>{"data"=>{"type"=>"shops", "id"=>"613"}}, "language"=>{"data"=>{"type"=>"languages", "id"=>"374"}}}, "type"=>"shop-languages"}, "controller"=>"shop_languages", "action"=>"create", "shop_id"=>"613"} permitted: false>
```

After being parsed by `ActiveModelSerializers::Deserialization.jsonapi_parse!`:

```
{:shop_id=>"613", :language_id=>"374"}
```

Comment: It seems like we can create a new AMS serialized model like that: `serialization = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(resource, options)`, where resource is initiliazed like that: `resource = SomeResource.new(title: 'ActiveModelSerializers', body: 'Convention over configuration')`. So I'll have probably to replace my `valid_params` json with this trick.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I came to is as follows:

I defined a helper method in `spec/support/request_spec_helper`:

```
def ams_json(model, attrs = {})
  resource = model.new(attrs)
  serialization = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(resource)
  serialization.to_json
end
```

I modified the everywhere in the request spec `valid_params` creation by calling the above helper method(`ShopLanguage` is the model name the resource json should be initialized):

```
let(:new_language) { create(:language, tag: 'nl-BE') }

let(:valid_params) { ams_json(ShopLanguage, shop_id: shop_id, language_id: new_language.id) }

before { post "/shops/#{shop_id}/languages", params: valid_params, headers: headers }
```

And it passed. Hop this helps. If there is a better solution it is always welcomed!